# Swagger response header setting

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am trying to write a swagger json-schema, the response produces either one of these

- png image
- jpeg image
- gif image
- String

So, how should i set the response header content type and also the produces MIME type?

[enter link description here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore-minimal.json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
/imagePath:
  get:
    summary: Something ...
    produces: [ image/*, text/plain ]
    responses:
      ...
```